# How to send user defined details to activity in Bot Framework App Or How to access BotData in my dialog class

Tags: bots, botframework, formbuilder

I have two questions

1) How to send custom values to Activity in Bot Framework?
I have below code in post method

```
UserDetails usr = new UserDetails();
usr.LoginID = l.LoginID
userData.SetProperty<string>("LoginID", usr.LoginID);
sc.BotState.SetUserData(activity.ChannelId, activity.From.Id, userData);
```

Now I want to access this property in my Dialog/FormBuilder class, How to achieve this?

Below is my formbuilder class

```
[Serializable]
public class FlightBooking
{
public static IForm<FlightBooking> BuildForm()
    {
    return new FormBuilder<FlightBooking>().Message("Tell me flight details!")
    .Field(nameof(title))
    ....
    ....
    }
}
```

---

2) How to access BotData user defined properties in FormBuilder/Dialog class?

As in above code, you can see that I have set EmailId property, how to access that property value in formbuilder class?

Comment: Can you clarify question #1? Please update the post a bit.. as it's confusing, you have parts of the question #2 above it.

Comment: My 1st and 2nd question are similar, I just observed it, Anyway thanks Ezequiel for reading out my question. Eric just cleared my doubt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) I don't understand what you're doing with `BotState`.  The question you asked is "How to send custom values to Activity...", but you are actually saving values into `UserData`.  Also, the code you've provided does not seem complete.

You can save `UserData` like this:

```
var stateClient = activity.GetStateClient();
BotData userData = stateClient.BotState.GetUserData(activity.ChannelId, activity.From.Id);
userData.SetProperty<string>("LoginID", l.LoginID);
stateClient.BotState.SetUserData(activity.ChannelId, activity.From.Id, userData);
```

2) You can send the activity.ChannelId and activity.From.Id to the BuildForm method:

```
await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, ()=> FormDialog.FromForm(() => FlightBooking.BuildForm(activity.ChannelId, activity.From.Id)));
```

and create the `StateClient`, and access the `UserData`:

```
public class FlightBooking
{
    public string title { get; set; }
    public static IForm<FlightBooking> BuildForm(string channelId, string userId)
    {
        string appId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MicrosoftAppId"];
        string password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MicrosoftAppPassword"];
        StateClient stateClient = new StateClient(new MicrosoftAppCredentials(appId, password));
        BotData userData = stateClient.BotState.GetUserData(channelId, userId);
        var loginId = userData.GetProperty<string>("LoginID");

        //do something with loginId?

        return new FormBuilder<FlightBooking>().Message("Tell me flight details!")
            .Field(nameof(title))
            .Build();
    }
}
```

But, you could also just send the entire activity object to the BuildForm method, and not bother with UserData at all.

Comment: Thanks Eric. Will try this and will come back if i faced more issue :-)

Comment: I have below code that navigates me to Flighbooking FormBuilder class i want to pass activity to BuildForm, How to achieve this? BuildFormDelegate<FlightBooking> MakeFlightBookingForm = 
    FlightBooking.BuildForm();
    var FlightBooking = new FormDialog<FlightBooking>(cb, 
    MakeFlightBookingForm, FormOptions.PromptInStart, null);
    context.Call<FlightBooking>(FlightBooking, FlightBookingComplete);

Comment: Please post the code in your question, or a new question.  It is difficult to read in a comment.